# Equivalence Relations and Mappings

Tags: equivalence-relations

I have come across this statement in a book of Mathematical Physics. A map $\phi\colon X \to Y$ defines an equivalence relation R on the domain X by aRb if and only if ф(a)=ф(b).  How to proceed with the properties of the equivalence relation and end up at  ф(a)=ф(b).

Comment: That’s not what you want to “end up at”. What you want to show is: (i) for all $a\in X$, $aRa$ holds; (ii) if $aRb$ holds, then $bRa$ holds; and (iii) If $aRb$ and $bRc$ both hold, then $aRc$ holds. You **define** $aRb$ to be the relation “$\phi(a)$ is equal to $\phi(b)$”.

Comment: If I started with Ф(a)=Ф(b) and proved that this is n equivalence relation, then I still need to prove If I have an equivalence relation R defined on X then Ф(a)=Ф(b). It is so because of the "If and only If", this is what I knew from the book "how to think like  a mathematician" as I am  not a Mathematician

Comment: “then I still need to prove If I have an equivalence relation $R$ defined on $X$ then $\phi(a)=\phi(b)$”. Sorry, but no; that’s nonsense. You do not have to prove any such thing. The “if and only if” clause means that the relation $aRb$ is defined to hold exactly when $\phi(a)=\phi(b)$. You are misunderstanding and misinterpreting the statement.

Comment: That is, the statement says that $R$ is precisely the set $R=\{(a,b)\in X\times X\mid \phi(a)=\phi(b)\}$. The “if and only if” is because this is a definition: $aRb$ will hold if $\phi(a)=\phi(b)$, *and* if $\phi(a)=\phi(b)$, then $aRb$ holds. So $aRb$ exactly when, and only when, $\phi(a)=\phi(b)$.

Comment: See also" [Show that R is an equivalence relation on X for x, y in X iff f(x) = f(y)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/932226), [Prove that the relation on $X$ given by $x\sim y$ if $f(x)=f(y)$ is an equivalence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/236777), [How to prove that a1 ∼ a2 ⇔ f(a1) = f(a2) is an equivalence relation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1028534), etc.

Comment: I will just take the benefit of the doubt as you are a mathematician and I am not.

Answer (score 2):

You have misconstrued/misunderstood the role that the "if and only if" is playing in the statement.

The "if and only if" is part of the definition of $R$, not part of what you are trying to prove/the statement being given.

Specifically, definitions are almost always "if and only if" statements: we say X if and only if Y; that is, when Y, then we say X, when we say X, that means that Y.

For instance:

> We say a subset $\mathbf{W}$ of a vector space $\mathbf{V}$ is a *subspace of $\mathbf{V}$ **if and only if** it is a vector space in its own right under the operations of $\mathbf{V}$ restricted to $\mathbf{W}$.

This means that: (i) if we say that $\mathbf{W}$ is a subspace of $\mathbf{V}$, that means that it is a subset that is a vector space under the restricted operations; **and** (ii) that $\mathbf{W}$ happens to be a subset of $\mathbf{V}$ that is a vector space under the restricted operations, then we will say $\mathbf{W}$ is a subspace.

You will sometimes see people who make definitions stating only "if". For example,

> Two integers $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime if their greatest common divisor is $1$.

Formally, that says that **if** their gcd is $1$, then $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. But it may seem like it leaves open the possibility that $m$ and $n$ are "relatively prime" under some other conditions too. That is, we are saying "A if B", which formally means $B\implies A$; this certainly means that if $B$ is true than $A$ is true, but it does not mean that if $A$ is true then $B$ must necessarily also be true.

So to avoid that possible reading, we say that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime if and only if their greatest common divisor is $1$. This is a *definition*. It says that is the situation under which we will say they are relatively prime, and the *only* situation in which we will say so.

Similarly with the issue at hand. You are given two sets $X$ and $Y$, and a function $\phi\colon X\to Y$. We want to define a binary relation $R$ on $X$. We say:

> $xRy$ if and only if $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$.

This means: when $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$, we will then have $xRy$; and if we have $xRy$, then it must be the case that $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$.

The statement to be proven then is just:

> $R$ is an equivalence relation on $X$.

You seem to have misunderstood the statement as saying

> The following are equivalent:
>   1. $R$ is an equivalence relation on $X$.
>   2. $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$.

Which of course would be difficult to establish, as it is nonsensical as written, because there is no connection between $R$ and $\phi$.

I hope this helps.

---

At the risk of being confusing, here is something which *is* true:

> Let $X$ be a set, and let $R$ be a relation on $X$. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. There exists a set $Y$ and a function $\phi\colon X\to Y$ such that $xRy$ holds if and only if $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$.
> 2. $R$ is an equivalence relation.

The proof that 1 implies 2 is the statement you are proving here. The proof that 2 implies 1 has to do with the fact that an equivalence relation induces a partition on $X$ into equivalence classes, and that then one can define $Y$ to be the set of equivalence classes under $R$, denoted $X/R$, and let $\phi$ be the function that sends each $x\in X$ to its equivalence class in $Y$. But this is a different statement from the one you have on hand.

Comment: I appreciate your contribution, it definitely helped. On addition I am concerned with the fact that R partitions X into equivalence classes and is defined as X/R or the factor space. These equivalence classes are the inverse images of the singletons of Y, or so mentioned in the book.

Comment: @Derhham: I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: How the equivalences classes defined by R are the inverse images of the singletons of Y

Comment: @Derhham: This is very basic material that you can find in almost any textbook that covers equivalence relations. It's known as the Fundamental Theorem of Equivalence Relations. Given an equivalence relation $R$ on the set $X$, an $x\in X$, the *equivalence class of $x$* is the set $[x]_R = \{a\in X\mid xRa\}$. It is then not hard to verify that two equivalence classes are either disjoint or equal, and that they give a partition of $X$. If $R$ is defined via a function, so $[x]_R = \{a\in X\mid f(a)=f(x)\}$, then it should be rather obvious that $[x]_R=f^{-1}(\{f(x)\})$.

Comment: thank you, It might be true that my questions are a bit naive, but as a Physicist who  should acquire knowledge in many disciplines of mathematics to do research in String Theory related topics, these are the struggles.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin - If you don’t mind me asking just so I understand: the *if and only if* in the sentence “Let $R \subseteq X \times X$ be a relation defined by $xRy$ if and only if $\phi(x) = \phi(y)$” is part of the definition of $R$ and has nothing to do with $R$ being an equivalence relation?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: Correct. It essentially says $R=\{(x,y)\in X\times X\mid \phi(x)=\phi(y)\}$. That is, $R$ consists precisely of all pairs in which the image of the first coordinate equals the image of the second coordinate. Every pair in $R$ satisfies that condition, and every pair that satisfies that condition is in $R$ (and that is why we say "if and only if", because we are saying "if it satisfies the condition it is in $R$" (the "if") and "if it is in $R$ then it satisfies the condition" (the "only if").